# Unable to set Layer Selection value on Data Transfer modifier via Python

Tags: python, scripting

When the Source vertex group named "ALL", How to change the value of the vertex group "ALL"?

[image]

When run `bpy.context.object.modifiers["Data Transfer"].layers_vgroup_select_src = 'ALL'`, it set the value to `All Layers`, not the vertex group `"ALL"`

Comment: I think you have to rename the vertex group name for the source object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertex group name can not conflict with the "All layers" value.

"All layers" value is "ALL".

So if the vertex group is also named "ALL", that can not work.

Simply rename the vertex group for the source object differently. For instance "All" (not "ALL").